# Dual booting challenges!

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

Okay, so before I ask this I have been trolling forums for days and tried numerous suggestions.  The situation I have is I can't dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.  Sounds simple.

So I've tried:

1. disabling fast boot
2. disabling secure boot
3. attempted to change UEFI settings from Windows and BIOS (my hardware is from 2008 so that's not even an option)
4. changed IDE/ACHI modes
5. forced my CDROM drive to EFI mode
6. booted from Linux live CD and a thumb drive
7. bootrepair from Linux LiveCD and;
8. (from windows) shrunk my C: disk and have not formatted it.  My BIOS does not have any sort of 'legacy mode' options.

When the Ubuntu installer comes up, it can't detect an existing operating system - so I choose 'do something else'.  It wont detect C:  Although my raid5 array does show up,  I've tried gparted but that wont even start without generating an error.  If push I through the error, again the raid5 array shows up but not C: - this is where I want to install Linux.

Any ideas?  I was thinking perhaps installing Linux first then windows for a dual boot solution, however if the Linux installer is not detecting C: - how can I even do that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Windows is in hibernation mode and so the disk is still mounted.

To change it **boot into the Windows 10 installation** and **disable hibernation**.

To disable hibernation open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

After having done this - **shutdown** the machine **completely** - **do NOT reboot** !

Now **reinstall GRUB boot loader** to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.

**Boot from the Ubuntu installation media** - open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sd*
update-grub
```

Note:

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

To identify the partition numbers use **GParted** - it is included in the Ubuntu installation media.

Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu in UEFI settings to be the default operating system to boot.

Note : It is not clear from your question whether you already have Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS installed.
In case you don't have any Ubuntu edition installed ... you can skip the part of reinstalling GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your grub. I had the same issue and fixed it by updating the grub.

In the terminal type `sudo update-grub`, wait for the update to finish and reboot your PC.